# How to make smooth animations in java swing

Tags: java, swing, animation

Hi I'm using the Timer class and the repaint method for the JPanel, but whenever I hit DOWN and the space ship moves halfway down the screen, it shrinks and stays in place.  It never reaches the bottom of the window.  It is the same when I move it to the RIGHT.

Also when I try to place it in a differnt y position, the background isn't black anymore.  Can someone help me with this please?  Here is a sample of my code:

```
package javapaint;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SpaceShipFlight 
{
    private JFrame windowFrame;
    private BufferedImage shipSprite;
    private BufferedImage spaceBackground;


    /** MAIN METHOD **/

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    SpaceShipFlight window = new SpaceShipFlight();
                    window.windowFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    /** CONSTRUCTOR **/

    public SpaceShipFlight() throws IOException
    {
        /*************************************************************************
                               SPACE SHIP FLIGHT JFRAME
        *************************************************************************/

        windowFrame = new JFrame("Space Ship Flight");


        windowFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 950, 700);


        windowFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);





        /*************************************************************************
                           SPACE SHIP FLIGHT SPRITES (FOR DRAWING)
        *************************************************************************/

        spaceBackground = ImageIO.read(new File("Space (Medium).png")); 
        // 450 x 374


        shipSprite = ImageIO.read(new File("Ship Sprite.png"));
        // 64 x 64 png of space ship





        /*************************************************************************
                           SPACE SHIP FLIGHT JPANEL (FOR DRAWING)
        *************************************************************************/

        SpacePanel spacePanel = new SpacePanel();



        windowFrame.add(spacePanel);



        /*************************************************************************
                                 SPACE SHIP FLIGHT TIMER 
        *************************************************************************/

        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new AnimationListener(spacePanel));
        timer.start();






        /*************************************************************************
                           EVENT HANDLER TO MOVE SPACE SHIP
        *************************************************************************/
        /*
        EventHandler <KeyEvent> moveShip = new EventHandler<KeyEvent> ()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) 
            {
                if (event.getCharacter().equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
                {
                    spacePanel.setX( spacePanel.getX() + 1 );
                }
            }

        };

        */

        KeyListener moveShip = new KeyListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && spacePanel.getX() < 375)
                {
                    spacePanel.setX( spacePanel.getX() + 5 );
                    spacePanel.repaint();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && spacePanel.getX() > 0)
                {
                    spacePanel.setX( spacePanel.getX() - 5);
                    spacePanel.repaint();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && spacePanel.getY() > 0)
                {
                    spacePanel.setY( spacePanel.getY() - 5);
                    spacePanel.repaint();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && spacePanel.getY() < 700)
                {
                    spacePanel.setY( spacePanel.getY() + 5 );
                    spacePanel.repaint();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X)
                {
                    System.out.printf("X: %d, Y: %d\n", spacePanel.getX(),
                                                            spacePanel.getY());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
            {

            }

        };





        windowFrame.addKeyListener(moveShip);




    }





    /** ANIMATION LISTENER CLASS **/

    public static class AnimationListener implements ActionListener
    {
        private SpacePanel panel;
        private Graphics graphics;


        public AnimationListener(SpacePanel panel)
        {
            this.panel = panel;
            this.graphics = panel.getGraphics();
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            panel.repaint();
        }

    }





    /** SPACE PANEL SUBCLASS **/

    public class SpacePanel extends JPanel
    {
        // Variables for the space ship's position temporarily placed here
        private int x;
        private int y;


        // Constructor
        public SpacePanel()
        {
            super();

            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }


        // Getters
        public int getX()
        {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }


        // Setters
        public void setX(int newX)
        {
            x = newX;
        }

        public void setY(int newY)
        {
            y = newY;
        }






        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage(spaceBackground, 0, 0, this);
            g.drawImage(shipSprite, x, y, this);
        }
    }









}
```

Comment: It's not possible to run your program since it relies on some images.

Comment: `panel.getGraphics();` - no, nope, don't

Comment: One of the core problems is, `keyPressed` events can repeat while the key is held, apart from using the Key Bindings API, it a better solution be to set a flag when the key pressed and reset the flag when it's released, then use `Timer` as an update loop to update the position of the entities within it. Also beware, you are (unintentionally) overriding the `getX` and `getY` methods of `JPanel` which is going to cause no end of issues and the component will try and reposition itself within the container and the image will be offset again by that same amount

Comment: First hint: you want us to spend our time to help you solve your problem. So you please make that as easy as possible - starting with: properly indent/format all of your code; instead of dropping something here that contains 75% empty lines or so. Beyond that: every time when you put up a big comment that says what the next lines are doing: put those lines into a method that has a clever name; and remove that comment.